# Matlab (extracting files)

Tags: matlab

I have this command

```
ncid(i) = netcdf.open('3B42_daily.1998.01.01.7.SUB.nc','NC_NOWRITE');
```

and I have to change the months and days till 365 days to get data from 365 files  linked with the working folder in my matlab.

Kindly guide how I can read/extract those 365 files

here month=01, day=01, all the rest of things remain same.

Thank You

Comment: If you thought that "Matlab" is sufficient as a title: you were wrong. Please try harder.

Answer (score 0):

There are simple functions to deal with netCDF files. You may read about ncinfo, ncdisp,ncread etc. To read all ncfiles present in the folder, you may proceed like below.

```
dinfo = dir('*.nc');
    for K = 1 : length(dinfo)
      thisfilename = dinfo(K).name;  %just the name
      thisdata = ncread(thisfilename,'your variable'); %load your needed variable from this file
      %do something with the data
    end
```

Comment: Thank you Siva Srinivas Kolukula :)

I will check this and will let you know the solution